# Cannot install gcov without version suffix

Tags: gcov, lcov, ubuntu-19.04

I try to install `gcov` to be able to generate coverage reports. I'm on machine `Ubuntu 19.04` and have installed `gcov-8`, which is working pretty well.

The problem is (as I can understand) that `lcov` tries to use `gcov` instead `gcov-8`. If I install `gcc-9`, the `gcov` is going to be installed, but in this case, I'm getting version mismatch problems.

Can anyone help me to figure out what to do to?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem resolved. Just removed and reinstalled `gcc`.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu there is a standard approach using `update-alternatives` command

```
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcov gcov /usr/bin/gcov-8 800
```

Which is basically almost the same as creating a symlink from `/usr/bin/gcov` to `/usr/bin/gcov-8`, but has better maintainability

`800` is just a random number, "priority" which will make sense only when you have several alternatives